# R filter function won't filter out results

Tags: r, azure

I'm trying to find all rows where values exist between a top and bottom depth value in Azure ML. I'm using dplyr's filter function, and the code doesn't throw an error. But when I look at the results it hasn't filtered anything. Can somebody see where I'm going wrong?

```html
library(dplyr)

Upper_Depth<-dataset1$Upper_Depth
Lower_Depth<-dataset1$Lower_Depth
TopMD<-dataset1$TopMD
BaseMD<-dataset1$BaseMD

  # Filter where the Perf is within the Upper and Lower Depth intervals:
  #select(Upper_Depth, Lower_Depth, TopMD, BaseMD) %>%
  filter(dataset1, Upper_Depth > TopMD & Lower_Depth < BaseMD);
  
  # Subset the data where the perfs are in the L_WSEC_A:
  #subset(dataset1, Upper_Depth > TopMD & Lower_Depth < BaseMD)
  
  full_data <- dataset1

# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port
maml.mapOutputPort("full_data")
```

I tried the subset function but get the same result. I apologize because I'm very new to r and Azure ML Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to R!

The reason your code is not working as expected is because the first four lines in your script are assigning vectors. This would work fine if you were using `base` R subsetting (try `?'['` at the console) and performing logic tests in the columns as vectors.

dplyr works somewhat differently. The metaphor is closer to SQL, treating each "column" in the dataset as a SQL field. So, you can work with your variables directly, without subsetting them out into vectors.

Try:

```
   dataset1 %>% filter(Upper_Depth > TopMD & Lower_Depth < BaseMD)
```

It should give you your `dataset`, filtered so that each condition evaluates as `TRUE`.

If you want to save the results, just left-assign them like this:

```
   full_data <- dataset1 %>% filter(Upper_Depth > TopMD & Lower_Depth < BaseMD)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! Works perfectly.